# Citation label instead of number of reference

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies

I have a problem regarding the bibliography in my document. My code is the following:

```
\documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{llncs}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\begin{document}

Hello world! \cite{wu2015deep}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{wu2015deep} Wu J, Yu Y, Huang C., Yu K. Multiple Instance Learning for Image Classification and Auto-Annotation. In CVPR 2015, pp. 3460--3469
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

And the output of my code is the following:

[image]

As you can see instead of [1], the reference is [wu2015deep].
Do you have any idea what is the problem that's causing this? I am using TeXMaker 4.5, compiling with the option:
pdflatex + Bib(la)tex + pdflatex (x2) + View PDF

Thank you very much in advance for your time and help! :)

Comment: You can't mix biblatex with `thebibliography` and \bibitem. You need a bib file with your entry.

Comment: As Ulrike says, you can't mix the manual way of creating a bibliography (`thebibliography`) with the automatic way of `biblatex`. If you want to use `biblatex`, refer to [biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864), [What to do to switch to biblatex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864) and linked questions. A nice starter guide is https://heim.ifi.uio.no/~dag/latex-links/biblatex-guide.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the following code you will get the [1]:

```
\documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{acronym}

\begin{document}

Hello world! \cite{wu2015deep}

\begin{thebibliography}{----}

\bibitem{wu2015deep}
%\textsc{Wu},  J. \textsc{Yu}, Y.  \textsc{Huang} C. \& \textsc{Yu} K. (2015) {\it Multiple Instance Learning for Image Classification and Auto-Annotation.} In CVPR 2015, pp. 3460--3469
Wu J, Yu Y, Huang C., Yu K. Multiple Instance Learning for Image Classification and Auto-Annotation. In CVPR 2015, pp. 3460--3469
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It worked but I had to do one more thing, compile it with the option pdflatex + View PDF.